# Corridor path by line path and width

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, geometry

I need to write a function, which generates corridor path by line path and width.

For example, I have array of coords of polyline:

```
var coords = [
  50, 50,
  150, 50,
  250, 100,
  220, 200,
  350, 100,
];
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCxb.png

Then I use function to get corridor path:

```
var width = 10;
var corridorPath = getCorridorPath(coords, width);
```

Function should return something like that:

```
[
  40, 50,
  50, 40,
  150, 40,
  157, 41,
  255, 90,
  260, 105,
  240, 170,
  340, 90,
  360, 90,
  360, 110,
  220, 215,
  205, 205,
  233, 107,
  147, 62,
  50, 60,
  40, 50,
]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3wxN.png

Comment: What have you tried so far? also it seems ambiguous on to what the coordinates should be in the 2 outer edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate parallel polylines and conjunctions.

For two neighbor edges **AB** and **BC** find normalized vectors **ab** and **cb**.

Calculate unit bisector vector:

```
 b = (ab + cb).normalized
```

Calculate length of bisector segments as

```
 len = d / sin(fi)
```

where d is offset (halfwidth), and fi is angle between vectors b and ab:

```
 fi = atan2(crossproduct(b,ab), dotproduct(b,ab))
```

Find offset points (left and right ones) as

```
B' = B + l * b
B'' = B - l * b
```

Note that you want to cut long triangles, so offset point is valid for side with acute angle, and you need to recalculate two points for cut cap - for example, get central point `B''' = B - d * b` and add vectors, perpendicular to bisector.

Comment: What does `B`, `B'` and `B''` represent?

Comment: @SGhaleb B is junction point of the source polyline. B' and B'' are points on new left and right polylines.